# Cleanup storageFolder.RoamingFolder all files winrt

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I would like to cleanup all files from the storageFolder.RoamingFolder in winrt
I can delete individual files but *.* does not work any ideas on how to aproach this ?

Comment: What kind of error do you obtain? Can you use us your code?

Comment: the code I am using right now to delete can be found here http://codepaste.net/gtu5mq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If deleting the contents of a folder is what you want to achieve a recursive method like this would work:

```
public static async Task DeleteFolderContentsAsync(StorageFolder folder,
   StorageDeleteOption option)
{
   // Try to delete all files
   var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
   foreach (var file in files)
   {
      await file.DeleteAsync(option);
   }

   // Iterate through all subfolders
   var subFolders = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
   foreach (var subFolder in subFolders)
   {
      // Delete the contents
      await DeleteFolderContentsAsync(subFolder, option);

      // Delete the subfolder
      await subFolder.DeleteAsync(option);
   }
}
```

Comment: If you just delete the folders it should also delete the contents of those folders, so you should only need to iterate the files in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this now, there is [`StorageFolder.GetItemsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.getitemsasync?view=winrt-22000#Windows_Storage_StorageFolder_GetItemsAsync) which returns all files and subfolders of the specified folder, so you can modify Jürgen Bayers answer to look like this:

```cs
public static async Task DeleteFolderContentsAsync(StorageFolder folder, StorageDeleteOption option)
{
    var items = await folder.GetItemsAsync();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        await item.DeleteAsync(option);
    }
}
```

which is a lot shorter and works if you do not need to tell files and folders apart.

Further, deleting a folder also deletes the elements within, so you do not need to call the method recursively.